# What is the role of the second mfrow in this code?

Tags: r

What is the role of the second mforw in this code? I mean `par(mfrow=c(1, 1))`

```
sales <- function(price) { 100 - 0.5 * price }
revenue <- function(price) { price * sales(price) }
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
 curve(sales, from=50, to=150, xname="price", ylab="Sales",main="Sales")
 curve(revenue, from=50, to=150, xname="price", ylab="Revenue",
main="Revenue")
 par(mfrow=c(1, 1))
```

Comment: It should bring the plotting window back to 1 column and 1 row.

Comment: When you doesn't  bring the second `par`, the revenue curve will not be shown.

Comment: I can't test for myself, but from my understanding the first `par` should allow for the 2 `curve` calls to be plotted one next to the other. The last one shouldn't do anything.

Comment: I did test, the second call to `par` is useless, as I thought. What version are you running?

Comment: I use the latest version. It is strange. Both you and Georgy Bolyuba tested and say that there is no need for the second `par`. But when I don't write the second `par` the revenue curve will not be shown.

Comment: The problem solved. When I copy the code and then paste it in RGui, if there is the second `par` I will see the revenue curve immediately, but if there is not  the second `par` I have to press enter key to see the revenue curve. Thank you for your help and please excuse me for getting your precious time.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `par(mfrow=c(1, 1))` at the end is an attempt to reset parameters for default graphical device. This way next time code plots something it will have exactly one plot.

A better option would be to remember parameters before modifying them `old.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)` and then reset all of them once you are done with your plot `par(old.par)`

Comment: When you doesn't bring the second `par`, the revenue curve will not be shown. Please test it.

Comment: @javad I did test it, for revenue curve to be shown you need the first call to par, i.e. par(mfrow=c(1, 2))

Comment: The problem solved. When I copy the code and then paste it in RGui, if there is the second `par` I will see the revenue curve immediately, but if there is not  the second `par` I have to press enter key to see the revenue curve. Thank you for your help and please excuse me for getting your precious time.

Comment: @javad the real difference in what you describing is the presence/absence of end of line after your second call to curve function. It has very little to do with par(mfrow=c(1, 1)) or anything else that could be on that line

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. When I copy the code and then paste it in RGui, if there is the second `par` I will see the revenue curve immediately, but if there is not the second `par` I have to press enter key to see the revenue curve.